# Bogus WPF / XAML errors in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

There are errors hanging around, but at runtime everything works.

Right now, I'm getting `Cannot locate resource 'img/icons/silk/arrow_refresh.png'.`

[image]

I've got a simple UserControl called ImageButton (doesn't everyone?):

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProj.src.controls.ImageButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Button Name="btnButton" Click="btnButton_Click">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Name="btnImage" Stretch="None" />
            <TextBlock Name="btnText" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

Which does what you'd expect:

```
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public partial class ImageButton : UserControl
{
    public String Image { set { btnImage.Source = GuiUtil.CreateBitmapImage(value); } }
    public String Text { set { btnText.Text = value; } }
    public double Gap { set { btnImage.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, value, 0); } }
    public bool ToolBarStyle { set { if (value) { 
        btnButton.Style = (Style)FindResource(ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey); } }
    }
    public bool IsCancel { set { btnButton.IsCancel = value; } }
    public bool IsDefault { set { btnButton.IsDefault = value; } }

    public event RoutedEventHandler Click;

    public ImageButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Click != null)
        {
            Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Where CreateBitmapImage is the following:

```
public static BitmapImage CreateBitmapImage(string imagePath)
{
    BitmapImage icon = new BitmapImage();
    icon.BeginInit();
    icon.UriSource = new Uri(String.Format("pack://application:,,,/{0}", imagePath));
    icon.EndInit();
    return icon;
}
```

I can't see the design view of any xaml file that uses an ImageButton like such:

```
<Window
    foo="bar"
    xmlns:wpfControl="clr-namespace:MyProj.src.controls">
    <Grid>
        <wpfControl:ImageButton ToolBarStyle="True" Gap="3" 
            Click="btnRefresh_Click" Text="Refresh"
            Image="img/icons/silk/arrow_refresh.png" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Why is VS complaining?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, there were a couple of answers to earlier questions containing edits I never saw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using Dependency Properties and Bindings when creating a Control. The benefits of this will be many, for example you'll be able to Bind the Image property for the `ImageButton` and you won't run in to problems like the one in your question.

Instead of using the setter in the Properties to set the Image source and TextBlock Text, you can bind them to the properties for the `ImageButton` `UserControl`.

**Update**
I put together a small sample project with `ImageButton` here: http://www.mediafire.com/?vlk4m7svttyjd6t

Your Xaml can look like this

```
<UserControl ...
             x:Name="imageButton">
    <Button...>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=imageButton, Path=Image}" .../>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=imageButton, Path=Text}" .../>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

And then you replace the CLR Properties with Dependency properties like below in code behind

```
public partial class ImageButton : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Image",
            typeof(ImageSource),
            typeof(ImageButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));
    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)base.GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ImageButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)base.GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    //...
}
```

For the Gap property you can either Bind Margin with a Converter or use the `PropertyChangedCallback` to set it in code behind.

Hope that helps

Comment: I've added your code as ImageButton2, and nothing appears when I use it with `<wpfControl:ImageButton2 Text="Hello" Image="/img/icons/silk/arrow_refresh.png" />`

Comment: @epalm: Did you add the `x:Name="imageButton"` for the `ImageButton` `UserControl` in xaml?

Comment: @epalm: Updated my answer with a link to a small sample project containing your `ImageButton` with the changes I suggested. Try to compare it to your version to see what's missing

Comment: Yes.  Even using `<wpfControl:ImageButton2 Text="Hello" />` simplified yields the same result (no control displayed).

Comment: @epalm: That probably means that the binding is failing and that leeds me to believe that I can't find the Control with ElementName=imageButton. Try the sample I uploaded

Comment: That works, much thanks.  Shows how much I still have to learn about WPF.  Still wondering why VS complains about my implementation though.  (PS. I posted my last message before seeing your sample project.)